# Custom Label Provider in SWT Table

Tags: swt, jface

"ITableLabelProvider " interface has given two methods to implement out label provider, 
     one of the methods is

```
     public String getColumnText(Object element, int columnIndex);
```

in this method **element** represents one **entire row**, based on the column index we will get data and set to table.

My requirement is , I want a method such that element represents **one column**,
so based on column index I can access data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment there is no label provider, which would provide element, representing just a column (even cell). It is actually quite logical, if you think about it. So, you should rely on column index to fetch the data (for example, having a `switch` by column index).

Another possibility would be to do it like this:

```
TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.LEFT);
tableViewerColumn.getColumn().setText("Column");
tableViewerColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
        return ((RowRepresentingObject) element).getColumnValue();
    }
});
```

Comment: I added combo box editing support for these columns, but the changes are not reflecting in the view.
I called tableViewer.refresh(), In the debug mode it is showing the changed value..

Comment: I don't think it is somehow related to this question. I would suggest you to ask new question and provide some code samples what did you do: how do you create your view and model, how you change it and what do you expect to happen.